# Unable to extract all points when converting tiff file to shape using gdal_polygonize.py

Tags: linux, geospatial, tiff, gdal

I am trying to extract elevation points from tiff file by converting it to shape file using gdal_polygonize.py command on Linux

The conversion is successful, however the shape file does not contain all the elevation points.

I am using the below command for conversion

```
gdal_polygonize.py NT60ne_DTM_2m.tif -f "ESRI Shapefile" NT60ne_DTM_2m.shp -fieldname elevation
```

Below are the screenshots of *NT60ne_DTM_2m.tif* and *NT60ne_DTM_2m.shp* which I have published on geoserver

**NT60ne_DTM_2m.tif**

[image]

**NT60ne_DTM_2m.shp**

[image]

I know the converted file is incomplete because I did the same operation in QGIS tool using *raster pixel to points* and below is its output

[image]
[image]

What am I missing here when using *gdal_polygonize.py* command for conversion. Why is it incomplete?

**UPDATE** : Add source file for other users to try [NT60ne_DTM_2m.tif](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wwOWnebYTnHz2zc_24j1ChWDZzDj9AYZ/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

The two functions you're comparing don't produce the same output. gdal_polygonize will create polygons connecting equal-valued pixels (in a single polygon). Compared to the QGIS function, which converts every pixel to a unique point/polygon regardless it's value.

It's unclear to me why your result of gdal_polygonize appears to contain points instead of polygons. That shouldn't be possible.

You could try doing the same from Python with `gdal.Polygonize`. When I use the snippet below, it seems to work as I would expect. The output are the red-lines in the image below, overlayed on the input raster.

```py
from osgeo import gdal, ogr, osr

ras_file = 'NT60ne_DTM_2m.tif'
vec_file = 'NT60ne_DTM_2m.gpkg'

ds_ras = gdal.OpenEx(ras_file)
src_band = ds_ras.GetRasterBand(1)
srs_wkt = ds_ras.GetProjection()

srs = osr.SpatialReference()
srs.ImportFromWkt(srs_wkt)


drv = ogr.GetDriverByName('GPKG')
ds_vec = drv.CreateDataSource(vec_file)
lyr = ds_vec.CreateLayer('', srs=srs, geom_type=ogr.wkbPolygon)

lyr.CreateField(ogr.FieldDefn("elevation", ogr.OFTReal))
fld = lyr.GetLayerDefn().GetFieldIndex("elevation")

gdal.Polygonize(src_band, None, lyr, fld)


srs = None
ds_ras = None
ds_vec = None
```

A subset, showing only the lower-right corner:

[image]

edit:

The snippet below is an example of writing each pixel to a feature (Point/Polygon) to disk, with the raster value attached as an attribute. You could avoid using Shapely & Geopandas if needed, but it would require a bit more code to use only OGR to create the vector-file.

The same technique could be use to output a Polygon but the creation of the [WKT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text_representation_of_geometry#Geometric_objects) would be slightly more complicated, requiring the extent of each pixel. That can be created by offsetting the currently used center coordinates with +/- half the resolution.

A method like this, using string formatting/parsing for a large number of points, will never be extremely performant.

```py
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely import wkt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from osgeo import gdal, ogr, osr

ras_file = 'NT60ne_DTM_2m.tif'
vec_file = 'NT60ne_DTM_2m_points.gpkg'

# read raster data & metadata
ds = gdal.OpenEx(ras_file)
gt = ds.GetGeoTransform()
xs = ds.RasterXSize
ys = ds.RasterYSize
srs_wkt = ds.GetProjection()
nodata = ds.GetRasterBand(1).GetNoDataValue()
data = ds.ReadAsArray()
ds = None

# mask to ignore nodata
assert np.isfinite(nodata) # else use np.isfinite / np.isnan
valid_data = data != nodata

# (outer) extent of raster
ulx, xres, _, uly, _, yres = gt
lrx = ulx + xs * xres
lry = uly + ys * yres

# convert extent to center of pixel
ulx = ulx + xres/2
lrx = lrx - xres/2
uly = uly + yres/2
lry = lry - yres/2

# create coordinate grids
mapy, mapx = np.mgrid[uly:lry+yres:yres, ulx:lrx+xres:xres]

# create normal DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(mapx=mapx[valid_data], mapy=mapy[valid_data], elevation=data[valid_data]))

# Use WKT Point to add the geometry (just a string column)
df["geometry"] = df.apply(lambda row: wkt.loads(f"POINT ({row.mapx} {row.mapy})"), axis=1)

# convert to actual GeoDataFrame
df = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df, geometry='geometry', crs=srs_wkt)

# save to disk
df.to_file(vec_file, driver="GPKG")
```

Comment: I am so naïve. My aim is to extract elevation points from TIFF file. For that I used gdal_polygonize.py, it resulted the same picture as you posted above. But I used PointSymbolizer style on geoserver. This resulted in the points instead of polygons. And again I'm so naïve here. I understood that gdal_polygonize is not the right tool for my purpose. I am looking for an alternative command line tool just like the QGIS's raster pixels to points tool. There are thousands of TIFF files which I want to convert, that's the reason I am looking for a command line alternative.

Comment: Is there any gdal function which does what QGIS raster pixels to points algorithm dos?

Comment: @Abhilash, I've added an example that might work for you.

Comment: Alright Thank you. I will try this example.